# Is it possible to pause a playing SWF file in Adobe Flex? How?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, loader, playback

I just wanna know if it is possible to pause a playing SWF file in adobe flex?
I have an SWF Loader and it plays my SWF file however, it does not have any capability (or built in function) that pauses the file.

Can anyone help me with this please? I'll appreciate some code to start with. :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the SWF done in Action Script 2.0 or 3.0 ?

Comment: it is done in ActionScript 3.0. I have tried creating an instance of a movie clip and assigning my SWF into the movie clip by casting it as such but that doesn't seem to work. I have also tried using Loader but it doesn't work as well. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stop();`

The following is an example of a swf playing and control is given to the play and pause and gotoandstop buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function playHandler():void {

                var file_mc:MovieClip = fileswf.content as MovieClip;
                file_mc.play();

            }

            private function pauseHandler():void {

                var file_mc:MovieClip = fileswf.content as MovieClip;
                file_mc.stop();
            }

            private function pauseat(frame:Number):void {

                var file_mc:MovieClip = fileswf.content as MovieClip;
                file_mc.gotoAndStop(frame);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:SWFLoader x="0" y="0" source="abc.swf" id="fileswf"/>
    <s:Button x="0" y="200" label="Play" id="playbtn" click="playHandler()"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="200" label="Pause" id="pausebtn" click="pauseHandler()"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="250" label="Pause at A" id="pauseAbtn" click="pauseat(1)"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="250" label="Pause at B" id="pauseBbtn" click="pauseat(2)"/>
    <s:Button x="300" y="250" label="Pause at C" id="pauseCbtn" click="pauseat(3)"/>
    <s:Button x="400" y="250" label="Pause at D" id="pauseDbtn" click="pauseat(4)"/>
    <s:Button x="500" y="250" label="Pause at E" id="pauseEbtn" click="pauseat(5)"/>

</s:Application>
```

**For completeness I have placed in the method for @Embed (it is not possible to get the original swf directly via SWFLoader [runtime vs compile time] but you can you can load the Bytes from a Class)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" addedToStage="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Embed(source="abc.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream") ]
            public var abc_cls:Class;

            public var ldr:Loader = new Loader();

            private var file_mc:MovieClip;

            protected function init():void
            {
                ldr.loadBytes( new abc_cls() as ByteArray );
                ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onSwfLoaded);
                swfcontainer.addChild(ldr);  
            }

            private function onSwfLoaded(e:Event):void {
                file_mc = ldr.content as MovieClip;
            }

            private function playHandler():void {

                file_mc.play();

            }

            private function pauseHandler():void {

                file_mc.stop();
            }

            private function pauseat(frame:Number):void {


                file_mc.gotoAndStop(frame);
            }       

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:Image id="swfcontainer" />
    <s:Button x="0" y="200" label="Play" id="playbtn" click="playHandler()"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="200" label="Pause" id="pausebtn" click="pauseHandler()"/>
    <s:Button x="100" y="250" label="Pause at A" id="pauseAbtn" click="pauseat(1)"/>
    <s:Button x="200" y="250" label="Pause at B" id="pauseBbtn" click="pauseat(2)"/>
    <s:Button x="300" y="250" label="Pause at C" id="pauseCbtn" click="pauseat(3)"/>
    <s:Button x="400" y="250" label="Pause at D" id="pauseDbtn" click="pauseat(4)"/>
    <s:Button x="500" y="250" label="Pause at E" id="pauseEbtn" click="pauseat(5)"/>

</s:Application>
```

I am sure now that it is the embed that was giving the problem sorry for any confusions. So if you need your swf as part of your file below should the trick.

The last way you can achieve getting assets into your flex workspace is to use [SWC Assets Method](http://www.airtightinteractive.com/news/?p=327).

Good Luck ! :D

Comment: yes i can use the stop() function but it stops the whole playing SWF file. What i really need is just to pause it then after clicking on the play button, it will just resume to where it was playing right before it was paused. Thanks for the code. :)

Comment: If it is timeline based you may need the gotoAndStop(last frame); Is it timeline based ?

Comment: sorry but i think this will sound stupid. i do not really know about that since i'm really new to using flex. i am trying the code you pasted above and on page load, it automatically plays the swf file so i don't really need to rollover/rollout. plus, i had to change the <mx:Script> into <fx:Script> for a particular reason which i really don't know. I hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: The Change from `<mx:Script>` to `<fx:Script>` means you are using Flex 4 SDK no worries. A timeline based swf uses the timeline provided in Flash CS3 software. Example if I just did a simple animation of a shape moving in the timeline, the above the code will say on rollover of the swf play the animation and as soon as it rolls out, pause it. If this is not working for you, you may either have to describe what your swf is doing (is it a simple animation ? is it a photo album ? etc) or use the gotoAndStop()

Comment: it is a video-like swf file. it plays exactly like the way a video does. anyway, this swf is just a test video i am using but the real swf file i would be using on my project is a flash-created rusting effect (corrosion) its simply like spraypaint being sprayed in small densities at a time.

what i observed was that on pageload, it automatically plays so i have to put an autoLoad="false" so that it wouldn't play on page load. this, however, will make the swf file not play at all. though i rollover my mouse, it still won't play.

Thanks a lot for helping me out. I appreciate your kindness.

Comment: haha. now this new code of yours confused me. But this is just the perfect timing since i was about to ask about some error I get whenever I publish my application. i'll try this one out. thanks :)